# How to remove empty space at bottom of RadEditor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

While setting the content in Rad-Editor it shows extra spaces bottom of the editor.
I have tried to use [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/empty-space-at-bottom-of-editor#oepXZI_3gUyK6stHJSl4Tw). but solution doesn't works.

```
  <telerik:RadEditor
        ClientIDMode="Static"
        ID="objRadEditor"
        AutoResizeHeight="true"
        EnableResize="false"
        EditModes="Design,Html"
        runat="server"
        StripFormattingOptions="all"
        Width="100%" Height="140px"
        ToolsFile="~/xml/RadEditorBasicToolsFile.xml">
        <ContextMenus>
        <telerik:EditorContextMenu Enabled="false" TagName="A">
        </telerik:EditorContextMenu>
        </ContextMenus> 
    </telerik:RadEditor>
```

Thanks in advance if you have solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the event "OnClientLoad"

```
 <telerik:RadEditor
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    ID="objRadEditor"
    AutoResizeHeight="true"
    EnableResize="false"
    EditModes="Design,Html"
    runat="server"
    StripFormattingOptions="all"
    Width="100%" Height="140px"
    OnClientLoad="RadEditorOnClientLoad"
    ToolsFile="~/xml/RadEditorBasicToolsFile.xml">
    <ContextMenus>
    <telerik:EditorContextMenu Enabled="false" TagName="A">
    </telerik:EditorContextMenu>
    </ContextMenus> 
</telerik:RadEditor>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function RadEditorOnClientLoad(sender, args){ 
        var editroWrap = document.getElementById(sender.get_id()),
        children = [].slice.call(editroWrap.childNodes); 
        for (var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            {
                editroWrap.removeChild(child);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```